# ASP.NET MVC List Concatenating Parent Table Field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is a bit embarrassing as I'm sure the answer is simple.

I'm using Entityframework and Code First techniques trying to build my first functional MVC form while following the excellent ASP.NET tutorials.

How do I display a string that includes Parent information to the table being queried.  I wanted to include a parent value in the string being used for the dropdown list .... or should I be doing this the opposite way and selecting the parent and have the children show up as a result of the selection?

I thought it would be as simple as adding to the model since it is already talking to its parent.  Intellisense is okay with it :-)

Model Class

```
public class SourceLocation
{
    [Key]
    public int SourceLocationID { get; set; }
    public int SourceID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Product Type")]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string ProductType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Source Location")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string SamplingLocation { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Sampling Location Notes")]
    public string LocationNotes { get; set; }
    public string SourceProductType
    {
         get
        {
            return CementSources.SampleSource + " " +  ProductType + " ex " + SamplingLocation;
        }        
}

    public virtual CementSource CementSources { get; set; }
}
```

}

The Controller referencing SourceSampleType is configured thusly.

```
// GET: Specifications/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.FieldID = new SelectList(db.Fields, "FieldID", "FieldName");
            ViewBag.SourceLocationID = new SelectList(db.SourceLocations, "SourceLocationID", "SourceProductType");
            ViewBag.SpecificationTypeID = new SelectList(db.SpecificationTypes, "SpecificationTypeID", "SpecificationTypeName");
            return View();
        }
```

When I try to create a new Specimen which is configured to show SourceSampleType, the error is:

---

*There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.*

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Source Error:

```
Line 28:             get
Line 29:             {
Line 30:                 return CementSources.SampleSource + " " +  ProductType + " ex " + SamplingLocation;
Line 31:             }
Line 32:         }
```

---

Am I not using this syntax correctly or is it something related to Eager/Lazy loading that I have yet to parse and understand?

Comment: Yes its related to related to Eager/Lazy loading. You need to remove that property. Instead you can use `ViewBag.SourceLocationID = db.SourceLocations.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value =x.SourceLocationID, Text = string.Format("{0} {1} ex {2}", x.CementSources.SampleSource, x.ProductType, x.SamplingLocation });`

Comment: Oarsome thanks for the quick reply. So I've killed the property and added this ViewBag into the Controller.  So I fixed the ToString() bit and run.  I hit the same DataReader issue when trying to Create a Specimen. '

Source Error: 
Line 66:             ViewBag.SourceLocationID = db.SourceLocations.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.SourceLocationID.ToString(), Text = string.Format("{0} {1} ex {2}", x.CementSources.SampleSource, x.ProductType, x.SamplingLocation) });
 
'

Comment: That should not be happening because the collection has been materialized. But try using `db.SourceLocations.Include(x => x.CementSources).AsEnumerable()......`

Comment: Well.... that did the trick :-)  Thanks heaps.  Did you want to answer so I can upvote you? 'ViewBag.SourceLocationID = db.SourceLocations.Include(x => x.CementSources).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.SourceLocationID.ToString(), Text = string.Format("{0} {1} ex {2}", x.CementSources.SampleSource, x.ProductType, x.SamplingLocation) });'

Comment: Give me 30 min (I've seen a good article explaining the issue previously and I want to see if I can find it to include a link)

Comment: Could not find the link, but I'll add it later when I find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you iterating through the results of `SourceLocation` but in each iteration, you executing another query to get the value of its `CementSources` property.

You need to remove the `SourceProductType` property from the model, and use `Include()` in the query to include `CementSources`

```
ViewBag.SourceLocationID = db.SourceLocations
    .Include(x => x.CementSources)
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.SourceLocationID.ToString(),
        Text = string.Format("{0} {1} ex {2}", x.CementSources.SampleSource, x.ProductType, x.SamplingLocation)
    });
```